# Quantmod package passing arguments in R

Tags: r, function, finance, quantmod, yahoo-api

I want to built a custom stock valuation function in R. My code is:

```
stock_valuation <- function(company1 = "GOOGL", start = "2018-04-01", end = "2018-06-01"){


stock1 = getSymbols(company1, src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)  

}


stock_valuation()
```

I want to have those default values as well. However when I run the function (as shown in the code) I receive no answer - nothing at all. What am I doing wrong? How to properly pass those arguments?

Or maybe there is a better way to scrap stock quotes?

In other words I want it to return data frame to global environment.

**Any possible answers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the default argument `auto.assign = TRUE` in `getSymbols`, your `getSymbols` call passes the GOOGL data into the environment inside the function, and assigns the string name "GOOGL" to your variable `stock1` (not the data), as expected by `getSymbols` by default.

Try this instead:

```
library(quantmod)
stock_valuation <- function(company1 = "GOOGL", start = "2018-04-01", end = "2018-06-01"){


  stock1 = getSymbols(company1, src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end, auto.assign = FALSE)  
  stock1
}


res <- stock_valuation()
```

`res` is an xts object, but you can easily convert this to a data.frame, such as like this:

`df <- data.frame(time = index(res), coredata(res))`